# Howto fix RAM Utilization in BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, bios

- Begin: Windows 7 Home 32-Bit
- I addded 4gb of RAM to the computer (3.12gb of 8gb Usable)
- I upgraded my PC to: Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit
- Added New Hard Drive
- Added New Graphics Card
- End: Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit, Only 3.12gb usable!!!

[Thats the chain of events]

So I checked around and apparently I should update the "RAM Utilization" in my BIOS to 'On'. After exiting and saving the BIOS. After restarting I booted up the BIOS (IMMEDIATLY) and saw All 8gb of RAM was being used. So I boot up my PC into the normal windows but all I get is a black screen. After looking around some more, I found out this is because no amount of RAM was allocated to the Graphics card!

Howdo I fix the RAM Utilization so only uses something like 7.2 gb of 8gb OR Allocates memory to the graphics card? *Please help I've been trying to figure this out **for months***

**I'VE ALREADY RUNNED MSCONFIG AND UPDATED BIOS**

Comment: You said you added a new graphics card? Does it not have onboard RAM? Are you using onboard graphics

Comment: Your description of the problem is woefully incomplete. What happens before you get the black screen? **Are you sure your monitor isn't just connected to the wrong video output?** What makes you think no RAM was allocated to the graphics card?

Comment: I would suggest booting the PC without the added graphics card and see what happens

Comment: Exactly what make/model of motherboard and graphics adapter do you have?  I have trouble believing you have a motherboard that lets you assign NO RAM to the video adapter. ;)

Comment: Identify a "no gpu memory allocation" condition via black screen (non-booting computer)? How was this done?

Comment: @horatio I found this out because suggestively a system would need atleast some memory reserved for core processes and for the graphics card. And since the BIOS reported no memory was appropriated it didn't work. If you need more proof, when memory was appropriated the system did boot up fine.

Can you please answer my question now? I'm sorry I'm getting really frustrated that no one is answering this.

Comment: You asked how to appropriate memory for the card and now you say you did and it worked. Allocating memory in BIOS *was* the question, so what is it you need help with?

Comment: @horatio **No!** Its an ***example:*** With the memory appropraited **WITHOUT** Memory remapped, and **ONLY** 3.2gb usable it worked. 

**WITH** Memory remapped **IT DIDN'T WORK** **Can you actually answer my question, please this is getting really really frustrating**

Answer (score 0):

Run MSCONFIG, check the Boot tab, Advanced options, if Maximum memory is checked, uncheck it. If it's not checked, try doing a BIOS update for the motherboard.

Comment: I already did this and updated the BIOS